# Angular6 circular slider

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a requirement of angular circular slider, Have tried JQuery sliders but i am not supposed to use. I am not able to get angular cirular slider, If any suggestions thanks  in advance

Comment: Might be this:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-circular-slider

Comment: you can try the https://roundsliderui.com/ plugin, which can be used in angular projects also. Check the below sample for the usage in angular7:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-round-slider